# Entity Framework Core and REST client - code organization

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework-core

I'm building a solution with three projects:

- `.Data` (holds Entity Framework Core-classes and `Writer.cs`)
- `.ConsoleApp` (Startup project, calls `Writer.cs`)
- `.CloudTalker` (Web Services references and `Fetcher.cs`)

The purpose of the solution is to call REST APIs, get entities from the APIs and store them in a database using Entity Framework Core. All code is running fine but I am positive there are ways to improve the architecture.

Example code flow to fetch Customers from the REST API and write to the database:

1. `Program.cs` in `.ConsoleApp` instantiates `Writer.cs` and calls method `WriteCustomers()`.
2. `WriteCustomers` get the latest modified date for Customers in the database
3. `WriteCustomers` calls `GetCustomers( latestModifiedDate )` in `Fetcher.cs` in the `CloudTalker` project. This method returns and array of `Customers` (the class returned by the REST API, not Entity Framework).
4. `WriteCustomers` loops through the array, converts the REST-object to an EF Core-object and puts it in `_context.Customers`.
5. `Context.SaveChanges()` stores the `Customers` in the database.

Now to my questions/calls for opinions:

- Have I done a decent separation of concerns? What is bugging me is that either the CloudTalker needs to know about the EF classes or the EF classes needs to know about the REST classes. Which way is preferred? Should `CloudTalker.Fetcher.GetCustomers( lastModifiedDate )` return objects from the EF Classes or the REST type?
- How should I handle naming of the classes? Right now I have two `Customer` - the REST kind and the EF kind. Not pretty.
- Anything else I should do differently?

Thanks in advance for sharing any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that this should belong to codereview website but here's what I think about the architecture (I am disregarding the fact that this could be a simple project that can live with a quick and dirty solution)

The writer should be in a separate project and should only know about EF and DB, The fetcher should only know about REST and how to call remote services. You can then introduce a service layer that knows about the two former bricks and calls the fetcher to get the data, then pass the data to writer.

I assume there's no business logic so no need for a separate domain project. Your service layer can be directly in your UI/Console project.

For the naming, how about CustomerReadModel, CustomerWriteModel?

It seems that you also need to read from DB to get the last modification date, so I would suggest having a reader somewhere in your db project.